# Informatica router transformation-Issue

Tags: router, informatica

I am facing a weird problem with router transformation in Informatica. I am using it in my mapping where I check for a particular port's value and based on the condition, I route it to appropriate flow. While I debug, I see the value of the variable as expected, but the row is identified as "filtered" in the debugger. I have tried various other methods like trimming the variable (LTRIM/RTRIM) to ensure there is no trailing spaces which makes the router condition fail, but that doesn't work either. As a result, my rows which are supposed to be inserted into the target as bypassed. Have anyone faced similar issue? I am wondering if I am missing something here.

Comment: The data is not going to router plz review ur conditions once more

Answer (score 3):

When you run normally without the debugger are you experiencing different results?

As you know, "Filtered" means the condition is evaluating to false, so the only question should be around your condition.

**What is the data type of the port and what is your exact conditional expression?**

Mismatching data-types can cause unexpected boolean evaluations (ex. comparing an integer to a string without casting one side using TO_CHAR or TO_INTEGER respectively).